# What is the literary term used to describe the common Hebrew idiom in which the extremes are given to represent the whole?

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible, idiom

Often in the Bible (particularly the Hebrew portions) a certain figure of speech is used in which two extremes are given to represent the whole. I can't remember what it is called. Examples include things like:

He read this to the young and the old alike

Receive blessings from the heavens above and the depths beneath

Everyone shall eat the passover, both slave and free

Obey these laws in your going out and coming in, your rising and lying down

From Dan to Beersheba

Summer and Winter, Rain and Harvest

Etc.

These are not literal citations but are examples similar to expressions commonly used. This idiomatic form of speech is just about everywhere when you think to look for it. But what is it called?

Comment: Stack Exchange - English Language & Usage [merism](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170795/stylistic-rhetorical-device-used-by-obama-over-and-over/170819#170819)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you are looking for is 'merism'. Technically, a merism is a particular kind of synecdoche. A merism indicates an entire spectrum of an ens by listing its polar elements.

Some biblical examples of this poetry device in Jos 6:26 (eg: all his sons); 1 Chr 29:29 (eg: all the things David did); Psa 121:6 (eg: you are safe 24 hours a day); 139:2 (eg: you know everything I do).

I hope you find these examples useful.

Comment: I'm going to mark this correct as the first answer to give me the word I'm looking for, but it pains me to accept an answer with such poor grammar...

Comment: Sorry for my wobbly English.

Comment: @Truth This is a global website open to all English speakers, some of whom have English as their second, or even third language. 'Poor grammar' is not always a deliberate fault, but bad manners always is.

Comment: @Truth - fortunately, we have a "edit" button to help with this. In addition to fixing the grammar, it allows us to welcome our friends who may not be native English speakers and, as an added bonus, provide them with some useful pointers to improve their English skills.

Comment: Thanks to James Shewey for the proof-reading. Anyhow, I've re-edited the answer so that some concepts of mine do not were losed.

Comment: @James Shewey - Forgive me if I'm rude. It is unintended. Perhaps I need brushing up on my SO etiquette. I'm always hesitant to edit someone else's work for fear of overstepping my bounds.

Comment: @Truth - don't be - they can always revert it if they don't like your edit.